# javascript for hide on clicking anywhere in the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can any one help me for hide menu on click anywhere in body.
 Here is the link as same as
[enter link description here](http://ashobiz.asia/boot-extended15/ui/ui-323.html)

Right Now the menu open when we click on top Button icon , Is this possible to open on each button click and specific div open.

```
< script >
  <!-- ToolTip -->
  $(function() {
    $('.ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li').tooltip();
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ui-323 ul.ui-nav > li > a.ui-bar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!($(this).parents(".ui-323").hasClass("active"))) {
      $(this).parents(".ui-323").addClass("active"); //Add Class Active
    } else {
      $(this).parents(".ui-323").removeClass("active"); //Remove Class Active
    }
  });
});


< /script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$(".ui-nav").on("click", "a", null, function () {
  $('.ui-323').toggleClass('active')
});
```

When the main menu( ui-nav ) it toggles the active-class.
More on [jQuery-on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [jQuery-toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: This code is making the ,menu displayed when clicked twice.i need this to on single click, can you please fix this?